# Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

So I have created this code to calculate the cosine similarity between two columns in two different csv files, both columns includes lines of jobs descriptions.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

df = df = pd.read_csv("Green jobs description.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("ExtractedData_2006.csv")
jobs = df.Description.tolist()
jobs2 = df2.Description.tolist()

train_set = [jobs, jobs2]

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix_train = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set)  #finds the tfidf score with normalization
print "cosine scores ==> ",cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix_train[0:1], tfidf_matrix_train)
```

So when I run the code I get this error, I included the whole traceback in a picture to be clear

[code traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbCyY.jpg)

can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: Check the types of data in `jobs` and `jobs2`.  More than likely, you have a list that contains lists instead of a list that contains strings.

Comment: @James I printed type(jobs), and  it showed <type 'list'>. What can I do in this case ? do you have an idea

Comment: try `set(type(x) for x in jobs)`

Comment: @James what does this line do exactly ?

Comment: It gets a unique set of each object type contained in `jobs`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix it

```
train_set=jobs+jobs2
train_set=[tmp.lower() for tmp in train_set]
```

That's pretty much it. I just needed to add lower to the strings inside my list.